# Gerenciamento de memória/armazenamento de imagens em núvem pelo Flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter

Comecei a recentemente desenvolver um App em Flutter e estou tentando entender como ele usa a memória/armazenamento do dispositivo em relação a imagens hospedadas em nuvem.

Para melhor contextualizar é um App de Mercado, o consumo das imagens estamos usando da API da cosmos (https://cosmos.bluesoft.com.br/api), que retorna um link com a hospedagem da imagem por eles e o widget do Flutter seria esse (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html).

Ao solicitar o Flutter fará com que a informação da imagem fique cacheada na aplicação, aumentando assim o consumo de memória/espaço enquanto o App estiver aberto e quando finalizado limpando o cache dessas solicitações?

Além disso existe uma extensão de imagem melhor apropriada para utilização em aplicações flutter por causa desse consumo?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Olhando a documentação inclusa na pergunta, vemos no construtor `network` do Widget `Image` a seguinte descrição:

> All network images are cached regardless of HTTP headers.
> If cacheWidth or cacheHeight are provided, it indicates to the engine that the image should be decoded at the specified size. The image will be rendered to the constraints of the layout or width and height regardless of these parameters. These parameters are primarily intended to reduce the memory usage of ImageCache.

> Todas as imagens são cacheadas independente dos cabeçalhos da conexão. Se os parâmetros de largura ou altura do cache forem informados, serão utilizados para o engine do Flutter que a imagem deve ser decodificada neste tamanho. Isso não influencia a largura/altura de exibição no layout. Esses parâmetros são utilizados para reduzir o uso de memória do Image cache (Tradução livre)

Então vemos nesse pedaço da documentação que, se desejado pode-se armazenar em cache uma resolução menor desta imagem. É um ponto de personalização caso desejado.

Sobre a classe [ImageCache](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html) vemos que:

> Implements a least-recently-used cache of up to 1000 images, and up to 100 MB. The maximum size can be adjusted using maximumSize and maximumSizeBytes.

> Implementa um cache que por padrão tem tamanho de mil imagens e até 100MB. Esses valores podem ser alterados utilizando os parâmetros informados.

Com isso deduzimos que você pode [personalizar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47840716/10746978) seu cache para um tamanho máximo especificado, se preferir. Isso não irá crescer indefinidamente ou sem controle, independente do tamanho de seu aplicativo. (Se quiser você também pode limpar o cache atual com o método [clear](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageCache/clear.html).)

**Vale deixar claro**, que o cache especificado nessas documentações diz respeito a um cache feito para a **exibição da imagem**, e não para a obtenção da imagem em si. Isso é gerenciado automaticamente pela classe [ImageProvider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html). Até mesmo imagens guardadas *localmente* são armazenadas neste cache. É uma questão de economizar a *re-pintura/re-desenho* dessas imagens. Acredito só ser necessário preocupar-se com isso em casos excepcionais, como muitas imagens sendo exibidas simultaneamente (para geração de um mosaico, por exemplo).

Por isso, acredito que a extensão escolhida não influenciará muito. Sobre o tamanho do arquivo, as mais comumente utilizadas já são bem otimizadas para uso pela Web. Me refiro aos formatos JPG e PNG.

Se você quiser utilizar cache local de imagens hospedadas na nuvem pode dar uma lida [aqui](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images). Dessa forma o download dessas imagens não será necessário após a primeira vez, inclusive por dentre múltiplas execuções de seu aplicativo. Isso não é feito por padrão no Flutter e para tal deve ser utilizado um [pacote](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image).